# Formatting issue with md5deep

Tags: batch-file, hash, md5

I am making a program in batch and it requires a text file to be hashed then the hash has to be saved to a text file. I already have that part done but when it saves to the text file it saves like this

f558e01b798b0390ab6206679a6926a7 C:\Users\computer\Desktop\tmpfile.txt

So my question is how do I get the directory part to go away? "
Also the program that is generating the md5 hash is md5deep64."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/md5deep.html:

> **-q**
>
> Quiet mode. File names are omitted from the output. Each hash is still followed by two spaces before the newline.